# Can a mac compile c++ to a windows exe on Xcode or VSC2019?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, compilation

I have made the decision to buy a Mac and Switch to a Mac after using Windows for 7 years,
I'm just wondering if I can compile c++ to an exe file on either Xcode or Visual Studio Code 2019.

Because it would be more convenient if I could as opposed to either starting up my old laptop to do it or Booting up a VM Though if I have too I can.

Comment: Another idea: [run Windows in a VM (or via Boot Camp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126759/7582247)

Comment: I'll do it in Parallels Desktop since Boot Camp doesn't work on M1 Macs.

Comment: You could use mingw

Comment: The best you can do in the way of improving a Mac's UI is to install Windows on it.

Comment: I've not tried this on a Mac ARM machine, but you could try `brew install mingw-w64` to install the Minimalist GNU for Windows and GCC cross-compilers.  But if you need `cl.exe` in particular rather than `g++`, then that is a non-starter.  Visual Studio Code runs native on Macintosh, but that's just a programmers editor, and does not provide a compiler (or in your case, a cross-compiler).